# Swift confused about capturing values in swift and locality of variables

Tags: swift

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}
```

So I'm reading swift documentation and they define some function here with a closure inside it that basically uses the variables that are defined locally in makeIncrementer now this makes sense to me but then this is said:

```
func incrementer() -> Int {
    runningTotal += amount
    return runningTotal
}
```

> The incrementer() function doesn’t have any parameters, and yet it
> refers to runningTotal and amount from within its function body. It
> does this by capturing a reference to runningTotal and amount from the
> surrounding function and using them within its own function body.
> Capturing by reference ensures that runningTotal and amount don’t
> disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends, and also ensures that
> runningTotal is available the next time the incrementer function is
> called.

Now to me this doesn't make sense? Capturing by reference ensures that runningTotal and amount don't disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends? When that call ends don't those variables just get freed and the memory for them is basically just gone? They don't exist anymore? Until I call that function again in which the memory is allocated for them again but they are new variables am I wrong here?

And why would runningTotal not be available the next time the incrementer function is called? It's always created and initalized in makeIncrementer how would there ever be a case that incrementer cannot access runningTotal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Capturing by reference ensures that runningTotal and amount don't disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends? When that call ends don't those variables just get freed and the memory for them is basically just gone?

The key thing to notice here is that `makeIncrementer` *returns* a new function object, which is what has captured those variables. Normally, you would be correct: `runningTotal` is a local variable, so at the end of `makeIncrementer`, it would normally "go away".

Except, the `incrementer` function still needs to access it; the compiler notices this, and effectively extends the lifetime of the variable outside of the scope of `makeIncrementer`. Its lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the function object you return, and when *that* object goes away, so does the `runningTotal` variable. If you store the result of calling `makeIncrementer` in a property, for example, the `runningTotal` that was created inside of `makeIncrementer` would stick around until you assigned something else to that property; if you call `makeIncrementer` and don't do anything with the result, though, then it would go away immediately, as it's not needed anymore.

> Until I call that function again in which the memory is allocated for them again but they are new variables am I wrong here?

Every time you call `makeIncrementer`, you create a new local `runningTotal` variable that is distinct and separate from every other `runningTotal` variable created by other calls to `makeIncrementer`. Each of those variables is separately held on to by different functions created by every single call to `makeIncrementer` totally separately.

So:

1. Yes, every time you call `makeIncrementer`, memory is used for a new `runningTotal` variable, as it's a new variable, and
2. Because each new call creates a new variable which is captured by a newly-created function object, each individual `incrementer` will *always* have access to the `runningTotal` it captures — the point of the capture is to ensure that the variable will be accesible so long as the function object could be called

> And why would runningTotal not be available the next time the incrementer function is called? It's always created and initalized in makeIncrementer how would there ever be a case that incrementer cannot access runningTotal?

If the compiler didn't take care to extend the lifetime of the `runningTotal` variable, then when `makeIncrementer` returned an `incrementer` function object, the `runningTotal` memory would "go away" and potentially get reused for something else entirely (because the variable is local). If `incrementer` would try to use that `runningTotal` reference it thinks it has, it would be manipulating random memory, which would cause some serious problems.

Instead, Swift makes sure that this is safe, and that it can't go wrong.

Comment: Yeah thank you for some I kinda skimmed over the fact that it returned a function object once I actually realized that and thought about it for a second and read your comment everything made sense thank you.